# What happened to Android 2.0?

Tags: android

Installed latest SDK updates from Google and my project changed to target 2.1

I was able to manually set it to 2.0

My collegue has brand new install of SDK and he can't event target 2.0 anymore.

What does it mean?

Comment: Is it installed? Obsolete platforms aren't marked for installation by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is obsolete as devices have been updated past it

http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html

Comment: What if my target customer didn't update his device? Will 2.1 install on his phone?

Comment: Yes. You should not target API levels 2, 5, 6, or 9 as they are obsolete. You can still install them from the Android SDK Manager if you check the Obsolete option